# Preferred way to compare a structure to zero

Tags: c, data-structures, comparison

Today I came across a situation where I needed to decide if an entire structure that consists of about 40 elements is zero - meaning that each of the elements is zero.
When thinking how to make it as fast and efficient as possible, I thought of 3 different ways to do so:

1. compare each element to zero, resulting 40 if statements.
2. allocating a similar structure which is allready zeroed and `memcmp` it with the structure.
3. wrapping the structure in a union with a type big enough to cover all of it.

for instance

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    }
  uint16_t c;
 } STRUCTURE_A;
```

and then comparing it to zero.

I would like to know what you think about these solutions, which of them you find the fastest and the most efficient.
And if you thing of a better approach please tell me...
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with simply checking the whole struct in an `if` statement, like you might for a zero flag?

Comment: Have you implemented each of your three different ways and compared their performance? What did you find?

Comment: I can't see a portable way of doing it other than comparing each field, due to possible padding

Comment: @Platinum - Padding bits, uninitialized members (that are perhaps not needed by all valid data configurations), members that may be nonzero when conceptually "false", any of the above changing at some point in the future as your application expands.

Comment: Does it matter if it is as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Compare every member of the structure to 0.

This is the only safe way to compare two structures objects (even if one of the structure objects has all members set to the value 0). Don't use `memcmp` to compare a struct, the value of the padding's bytes in the structure is unspecified. Note also that it is not permitted to use the `==` operator with structure objects operands.

See this c-faq link on structure object comparison:

[Q: Is there a way to compare structures automatically?](http://c-faq.com/struct/compare.html)

Comment: If you have ensured that the struct contains no padding, `memcmp` is safe. While an implementation is technically allowed to add arbitrary nonsensical padding, in the real world padding is purely for alignment, and a properly-constructed, naturally-aligned structure will have no padding except potentially at the end. In particular, using `intX_t` and ordering them without alignment gaps is a good way to avoid any padding.

Comment: If the struct contains no padding, and `memcmp` actually *is* faster, the optimizer will surely see that and transform your comparisons accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your structure size is <= the word size of the processor, you can do your union trick, however, any good compiler should do this automatically, aka it would compact the `if`'s, allowing for clarity but still keeping performance up to scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For code clarity, and as others have pointed out, to avoid problems caused by padding, checking each member would be best.

For speed, start with something like this that just checks each byte to see if it's zero.

```
int iszero(void * ptr, int bytes )
{
   char * bptr = (char*)ptr;
   while( bytes-- )
     if( *bptr++ )
         return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Then optimize to do word-aligned comparisons.  Check out newlib's implementation of things like `strlen()` & `memcpy()` for examples on how that is done.

Comment: This is equivalent to `memcmp` and may have padding issues.

Comment: @R.. No, it's not equivalent to memcmp() because there's no superfluousness zeroed structure involved here.  The extra memory access in memcmp() is likely worse than double the memory access time because you do two reads every time AND you probably have cache trashing on large structures.   I had not considered padding problems.  But if you know there's no padding (e.g. in GCC using pragma pack), I'll stand by my argument that this technique is fastest.

Comment: By "equivalent" I meant it has the same behavior (and padding issue), but I invite you to compare the performance. Your code (byte-by-byte) is so slow that even with multiple reads, `memcmp` should win. A good `memcmp` compares 4, 8, or even 16 bytes at a time. BTW "packed" is not the way to fix alignment issues. My comment on ouah's answer is the correct way.

Comment: @R..,  I guess you missed comment about optimizing to do word-aligned comparisons (like memcmp).  I was leaving that as an exercise to OP and offered newlib as an reference impl.   While yes, you should take care in ordering fields in a struct to reduce the need for padding, that won't always eliminate padding, but rather move it to the end.  Then when you have nested structs, your theory goes out the window becauese you suddenly have padding in the middle again.

Comment: @R.., I should add that I am well aware that NO struct packing technique is completely portable, but every C compiler I've encountered in the wild has *some* technique for packing your structs.  I am also aware that tightly packing your structs will likely hurt performance in accessing non-aligned ints, etc.

Comment: It has a lot more problems than performance. For instance if `int x;` is a member of `struct foo bar;` and `x` is misaligned, `&bar.x` is not a valid `int *`. Passing `&bar.x` to a function expecting `int *` will result in misaligned read/write and `SIGBUS` or worse. Packed structs simply **should never be used**. Period.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7004/discussion-between-brian-mcfarland-and-r)